# Azure AD as SAML Id Provider - How and where to set SP unique identifier

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I have an app that supports SAML 2.0. I want to configure Azure AD as Id Provider. I want to store my SP's unique identifiers in Azure AD user profiles. I could not find how to do that.

More specifically, I am able to select any of the user profile attributes as the value for NameId in the SAML response. But I do not want to use Azure AD standard user profile attributes. I could set up user.extensionattribute1 but where can I set the value for this attribute?

Note:
1. I am using trial Azure AD with Office 365 subscription. I am able to set up Azure AD as a SAML-based SSO Id Provider.

Comment: Any update for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

1.Navigate to **Azure Active Directory** > **Enterprise applications** and select the application from the list.

2.Under the **Manage** section, select **Single sign-on**.

3.Select **SAML**. The Set up Single Sign-On with SAML - Preview page appears.

You can configure User attributes and claims here.

[image]

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-single-sign-on-non-gallery-applications